# When does this two-variable function change signum?

Tags: calculus, functions, monotone-functions

Let's consider a linear function of two real variables:

$$ f(x,y) = Ax + By + Cxy + D $$

For any chosen  $ x>1$ the function is strictly decreasing in $y$, starting with some positive value and then running down, eventually reaching negative values.

Is there a method to determine/approximate the set of pairs $(x*,y*)$ for which the function f changes sign of its values from positive to negative?

Comment: The function can only change its sign where it is $0$. The zero set is a hyperbola which separates the plane into regions of constant sign.

Comment: Btw. this is not a linear function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. For any $x \ne -C/B$, set $f = 0$ like this:
\begin{align}
Ax + By + Cxy + D &= 0 \\
(B + Cx)y  &= -Ax - D \\
y &= - \frac{Ax + D}{B + Cx}
\end{align}
to get $y$.

By the way, for $x = -C/B$, the equation becomes $A(\frac{-C}{B}) + D = 0$, which may be true, in which case the entire line $x = -C/B$, $y = $anything, is part of the zero-set, or it may be false, in which case that line contains no point where the function is zero.

Comment: Neat and straightforward - thanks!